# PySimpleGui - No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pysimplegui

I installed PySimpleGUI and copy/pasted the "Jump-Start" code into vs code. i tried to run it and it keeps spitting out the error

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
No module named '_tkinter'
  File "/home/x/Code/PySimGui/testing_it_out.py", line 1, in <module> (Current frame)
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
```

I have already installed tkinter using

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev
```

...help

edit:
Here's my code:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
            [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')] ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    print('You entered ', values[0])

window.close()
```

Comment: Welcome!. could you please share the exact code you're trying?

Comment: Check what versions of Python are supported by `python3-tk` package by executing command `dpkg -L python3-tk`.

Comment: it lists python 3.8 and 3.9 as supported versions

Comment: So is the Python used in VS code one of the supported versions?

Comment: Yep it is python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the steps

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv- installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev git
```

Add to ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Reload bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Install python latest version

```
pyenv install 3.7.0
```

list python versions

```
pyenv versions
```

set global version

```
pyenv global 3.7.0
```

check python version

```
python -V
```

install PySimpleGUI

```
pip3 install PySimpleGUI
```

That's it, now you are able to import PySimpleGUI.

```
import PySimpleGUI
```

Comment: I followed all the steps but when I tried setting the global version to 3.7.0 using ```pyenv global 3.7.0``` as you said, it still says ```Python 2.7.18``` after entering the command ```python -V```.

Comment: Hello again.

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout you can check it.